# Python telebot как редактировать сообщение без нажатия на кнопки, автоматически

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

надо чтобы бот сам редактировал сообщения после того как я ему напишу сообщение. Например

Я пишу: `/start`,
Бот выводит: Введите то  то,
Я это ввожу, и бот редактирует предыдущие сообщение на новое

Чтобы работало без кнопок.

В `def st(message): bot.edit_message` я не могу поместить, как сделать редактирование сообщение без кнопок.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите то то')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id - 1, text='вы ввели ' + message.text)


[Client]: /start
[Bot]: Введите то то
[Client]: 123
Бот изменит своё сообщение "Введите то то" на "вы ввели 123"
```

что в итоге даст

```
[Client]: /start
[Bot]: вы ввели 123
[Client]: 123
```

Comment: А можно дать изначально сообщению id например message_id = "1 "?   Если ввожу в bot.send_message, пишет, что нельзя

Comment: message id присваивается серверами телеграмм